# Jenkins running multiple batch files at once

Tags: multithreading, batch-file, jenkins

I'm looking for a way to either pause Jenkins or have Jenkins complete a task from a batch file before starting another batch process. Basically what I want is something similar to running:

```
start /wait batchfile.bat
```

but when I run this Jenkins just hangs and the process never actually completes. When I run something like this:

```
run %startpath%\firstbatch.bat

run %startpath%\secondbatch.bat
```

Jenkins runs both batch files in different threads and this causes a big problem for me. I need the batch processes to complete because they cook and copy assets. The final batch that gets triggered zips the assets and sends them on their way, but if the assets aren't done being copied, the zip starts without all the files in the directory. The only other way I can think of around this is to have each batch in a different build and adding a quiet period to Jenkins but that would just be a guess to how long the batch scripts are actually running for. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using "call batchfile.bat"  That should block until the batch file is done running.

Comment: This worked. I know I tried this because my batch files have to "call" other batches to run concurrent but for some reason I would get an invalid directory error, maybe because it didn't like my environment variables. Now it's working and even outputting to the console like it should. Thank you both for your answers. I was pulling my hair out over this and I knew it had to be something simple I was overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate build job for each batch file if you want them to run sequentially, but you don't need to guess how long they will take to run. In the configuration for the job that runs firstbatch.bat, select "Build other projects" in the Post Build Actions section and specify the job that runs secondbatch.bat.  This job won't be started until the first job has finished.

Comment: I attempted to to this also, and maybe I have my exit codes a little screwy because Jenkins will just run the batch file then exit with: Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
Finished: SUCCESS  Then immediately start the next build step but I know the batch has not finished because I can see the directory filling with files